# How to show that a set of vectors is a basis for U where U is a set of columns?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis

How to show that a set of vectors is a basis for U ? [image]

QUESTION

- Let U ={(x,y,z,w) \in R^4 | x= y+z+w and x+y = z+w}.
- show that s = {col {1,0,1,0}, col {3,0,1,2} }is a basis for U.

Comment: Surely there’s at least one example of how to do this in the reading that you were likely supposed to do or the lectures on this that you heard before attempting this exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You have to show:

1. The defining equations for $U$ are linearly independent, so that $U$ has dimension $2$.
2. The vectors in $S$ are linearly independent and belong to $U$.